# Crystal Reports If true then return number else return NULL

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal Reports, is it possible to have a function that returns a numeric value if the if statement evaluates to true and returns NULL otherwise?

I currently have

```
IF ({INDICATOR} = 'Y') Then
(
    {numeric value}
)
Else
(
    0
);
```

But since 0 is a possible value of {numeric value} it doesn't make sense. Rather, I would rather have that field come up blank if the indicator isn't 'Y', but when I replace the 0 with NULL it gives me a type mismatch error.

Is there a way for me to only show the value when the indicator is 'Y'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't return two different datatypes in a single `if` statement..If `if` is number then else should also be number.. instead try to split the statements and try.. something like below.

```
 IF ({INDICATOR} = 'Y') Then
    (
        ToText({numeric value})
    )

   Else if ({INDICATOR} <> 'Y') Then
    (
       ""
    );
```

Comment: I'm unable to return NULL in the second If, I get an error that says "The ) is missing."

Is there some other keyword for NULL or something?

Comment: I tried running my report yesterday with this and it is displaying 0.00 rather than "".

Comment: are you performing calculations with the number value or just displaying it in report?

Comment: Just putting the formula into the description section to display.

Answer (score 13):

If you truly want a null value and not empty try the following

create a formula called NULL then save it and close without entering any data in the formula area. Then in your formula above try

```
If {INDICATOR} = 'Y' then {numeric value}
else tonumber({@NULL})
```

Comment: how can a null be converted to number?

Comment: I have used this solution before and tested prior to sending my response :)

Comment: I get an error when I run the report with this saying the the string is non numeric

Answer (score 1):

```
If {INDICATOR} = 'Y' then {numeric value}
else {Command.NULLCOL}
```

The setup in Database Expert is to use Add Command with sql:

```
select null as nullcol
from dual
```

Then left join to it.

A returned null value can be very powerful, so your need for a null value should not be questioned. Null values automatically display differently to stand out. Compared to 0 or "", null values work correctly with DistinctCount function. Null values also work correctly with section summaries and crosstabs, which can save you a lot of work which is the whole point of using crystal.